# In Docusaurus v2, is there a way to handle redirects to <some URL path>/default.aspx that Sharepoint automatically inserts into every page?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, docusaurus

I have a Docusaurus site hosted under `<SHAREPOINT_SITE_URL>/`. The first time I visit the page from outside, I get `<SHAREPOINT_URL/default.aspx`, a route which Docusaurus doesn't understand. [image: First load]

But then as soon as I click any link within the site navigation, Docusaurus starts working perfectly and continues working unless I either:

1. Refresh the page
2. Open a new link to the site from outside

[image: After clicking a link]

I need to be able to create links to documents in Docusaurus from outside of Docusaurus itself (e.g. via email or in private messages), so I can't just tell users to rely on the internal navigation after they hit the initial 404 (and it's just a bad user experience).

I've tried using @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects with `toExtensions: ['aspx']` and with `fromExtensions: ['aspx']` and neither seem to make an impact.

I've tried using `createRedirects` but I don't really know what I'm doing and I don't see a lot of great examples out there using @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects for something like this.

```js
createRedirects(existingPath) {
  if (existingPath.endsWith('/default.aspx')) {
    return existingPath.replace('/default.aspx', '');
  }
  return undefined; 
},
```

## EDIT:

I got this working by swizzling the NotFound component and adding logic for react-router to handle this:

```bash
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic NotFound
```

`/src/theme/NotFound.js`

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFound from '@theme-original/NotFound';

function removeDefaultAspx(url) {
  return url.replace(/\/default\.aspx$/, '');
}

export default function NotFoundWrapper(props) {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
    if (currentUrl.endsWith('/default.aspx')) {
      const newUrl = removeDefaultAspx(currentUrl);
      window.history.replaceState({}, '', newUrl);
      const relativePath = new URL(newUrl).pathname;
      history.push(relativePath);
    }
  }, [history]);

  return (
    <>
      <NotFound {...props} />
    </>
  );
}
```

If there's a better way to handle this, let me know!